# I'm trying to make something that will remove the stone all around me

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make something that will remove the stone all around me so that when I run in a cave and look back the cave will show all the ores right in the open.

Can I make a command that spawns another command block right under feet at all times and that command block removes the stone all around me as long as I'm holding an item named WorldEdit.

And possibly another command to remove the command blocks (that remove stone) behind me so there's not too many command blocks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you do any research?

Comment: Well, you could try execute at @a[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:stick",tag:{display:{Name:"\"WorldEdit\""}}}}] run fill ~5 ~5 ~5 ~-5 ~-5 ~-5 stone replace air . Is that what you need?

Answer (score -1):

The command youre looking for is as follows:

```
/execute at @p run fill ~-30 ~-30 ~-30 ~30 ~30 ~30 glass replace stone.
```